# How to add to arrays in mongoose using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have this type of mongoose schema shown below:

```
const brandSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    brandname: {
        type: [],
        require: true,
    },
    frequency: {
        type: [
            {brand1 : []},
            {brand2 : []}
        ],
    },
    date: {
        type: [],
    }
})
```

I want to be able to add two brandname to it at the to, then id find the brand name then keep appending values to the array later. Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: You need to clarify your question. Especially last sentences. May be there are some typos

Comment: you're specifying untyped arrays (should they be string type, date type, numerics, or something else?),  and your schema specifies `brandname` has property `require` but the mongoose documentation says it should be `required`. Also for the property `frequency` I don't think that syntax is valid. You're trying to specify a `type` for frequency and you assign it an array of two items, which does not make any sense. Maybe instead of telling us what your schema is, you can tell us what you want to accomplish.

Comment: @RuslanZhomir it was a typo

Comment: @Kevin i want to be able to store two names in the brandname, i also want to be able to find each of the brand name then add count(in numers) to brand 1 or 2 such that i can have multiple values in the brand 1 and 2 array. is that clear enough?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) operator in [findOneAndUpdate](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/) method. Example:

```
Model.findOneAndUpdate(
  { "_id": model._id, "projects._id": id },
  {$push: {
    [`projects.$.path.${version}`]: {path: `${sha256}.${ext}`}
  }},
  (err, doc) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).json({status: 'error'});
    }
  }
);
```